# Usign spring:eval in struts 2 project

Tags: spring, struts2, jsp-tags, spring-el

Is it possible to use the `spring` tag in jsp file to get the value from property place holder?! (The project is struts 2 base and we are not using spring MVC)

Below are not working:

```jsp
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>

<spring:eval expression="@propertyConfigurer.getProperty('foo.bar')" />

<spring:eval expression="${'foo.bar'}" />
```

Any comment ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpringEL tags are supposed to work with Spring model on the view layer in Spring MVC. So it's doesn't work in Struts 2. However you can use Spring EL expressions in Struts controller. E.g.

```
@Value("#{ propertyConfigurer.getProperty('foo.bar') }") 
public void setSomeProperty(String property) {
   ...
}
```